# Como instalar o serve no eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse

Eu descobri que o eclipse Mars está cheio de problemas, então me indicaram usar o luna, mas o luna não veio com server, como vocês podem ver;

para encontrar essa opção vai em Windows >> Show View >> Other >> Serve

Mas essa opção não existe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifique o tutorial que encontrei na internet

http://www.devmedia.com.br/instalacao-e-configuracao-do-apache-tomcat-no-eclipse/27360

Como faço para instalar o serve no meu eclipse Luna?

era para está assim!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
                          Atualização
```

versão do meu Luna;

```
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2015.  All rights reserved. Eclipse and the Eclipse logo are trademarks of the Eclipse Foundation, Inc., https://www.eclipse.org/. The Eclipse logo cannot be altered without Eclipse's permission. Eclipse logos are provided for use under the Eclipse logo and trademark guidelines, https://www.eclipse.org/logotm/. Oracle and Java are trademarks or registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
```

Comment: Qual versão do Luna você baixou? A Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers?

Comment: acabei de atualizar minha postagem, obrigado por mim ajudar!

Comment: Ainda não consegui identificar o qual você baixou, pergunto isso porque dependendo do download feito pode vir com os recursos do servidor ou não. Para garantir baixe essa que te passei. Até o Spring utiliza um Eclipse customizado para apresentar os recursos do framework.

Answer (score 1):

Baixe o pacote [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars1) em que esta incluso o *Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools* que contém os componentes específicos para servidores, bem como as Views necessárias para criar servidores, alterar servidores, deletar servidores, configurar os servidores, dar deploy em uma aplicação, entre outras funções que tratam dos servidores, como, por exemplo, os servidores de aplicação JBoss Wildfly, Tomcat, GlassFish.

Para o JBoss Wildfly o mesmo utiliza outro pacote para tratar de seu servidor e os recursos que oferece, chamado *JBoss Tools*. Instalando apenas o *Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools* as opções para configurar o servidor do JBoss não estarão inclusas.

Você pode instalar o *JBoss Tools* a partir do Eclipse.

- Help > Eclipse Marketplace > Procurar por JBoss Tools e Instalar.

Referências:

https://eclipse.org/webtools/

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars1

http://tools.jboss.org/